# Cannot Post CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I'm having problems with a CSV file upload with requests.post method in python 3.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import csv
import requests

user='myuser'
pw='mypass'
advertiserid='10550'
campaignid='12394'
url='http://example.example.com/api/edc/upload/'+advertiserid+'/'+campaignid+'/'+'?encoding=utf-8&fieldsep=%3B&decimalsep=.&date=DD%2FMM%2FYYYY&info=1&process=1'
csv="myfile.csv"

with open(csv, 'r') as f:
    r = requests.post(url, files={csv: f})
    print(r)
```

The output is 'Response [502]'

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Don't call your file 'csv' since that's already the name of a library you are importing.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine I have a rest API to import the CSV file (Multipart encoded file)

[image: rest api call via postman]

corresponding python request should be like below.

```py
import requests

​
hierarchy_file_name = '/Users/herle/ws/LookoutLab/data/monitor/Import_Hierarchy_Testcase_v2.csv'

headers = {
  'x-api-key': **REST_API_KEY**,
  'x-api-token': **REST_API_TOKEN**,
  'accept': 'application/json'
}

files = {'file': (hierarchy_file_name, open(hierarchy_file_name, 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
url = "https://abcd.com"
response = requests.post(url +'/api/v2/core/workspaces/import/validate',
                        files=files, verify=False, headers=headers)
print("Created")
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

Note:
**Make sure that you don't add** `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` **in the header**

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the documentation of Requests library here: [post-a-multipart-encoded-file](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Change your request line to:

```
r = requests.post(url, files={'report.csv': f})
```

Comment: I'm reading it right now. I tried changing taht line but... same error. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
csv="myfile.csv"

url='http://example.example.com/api/edc/upload/'+advertiserid+'/'+campaignid+'/'+'?encoding=utf-8&fieldsep=%3B&decimalsep=.&date=DD%2FMM%2FYYYY&info=1&process=1'

files = {'upload_file': open(csv,'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening it in binary mode? And with specific 'text/csv' mime type?

```
with open(csv, 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post(url, files={'file': ('myfile.csv', f, 'text/csv', {'Expires': '0'})})
    print(r.text)
```

If it still does not work, try without the binary, but still with the rest.
If it stiiill does not work, print the exact error message. And 502 (Bad Gateway) might just mean that you're not targetting the right url. (you're not targetting example.com, right?

Comment: Thanks Samuel, Still not working... This is the error:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/api/edc/upload/10550/12394/">GET&nbsp;/api/edc/upload/10550/12394/</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>

Comment: Seems that the error is not on your side (if you're targetting the right url).
What's the full url you're targetting? (if that's internet-accessible?)

Comment: I cannot provide the url due to my company policies. I'll dig into it. Thanks!